# SocketException when reading file with BufferedInputStream

Tags: sockets, streaming

I'm writing a TCP Server and Client, in which the client will send the file and the server will save it. My send/save function is as following:

Server

```
public void saveFile2(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis); 
    String fileName = dis.readUTF();        
    File file = new File(fileName); 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);               
    int byteCount;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((byteCount = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Test byteCount = "+byteCount);
        bos.write(buffer, 0, byteCount); 
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Saved file"+file.getName());
    bos.close();
    dis.close();
}
```

Client

```
public void sendFile2(String xmlpath) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    File file = new File(xmlpath);
    System.out.println("Sending File : " + file.getName());
    dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    int bytesCount;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    System.out.println("Sending file to server.");
    while ((bytesCount = fis.read(buffer)) > 0 )
    {
        System.out.println(bytesCount);
        bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesCount);
    }
    System.out.println("Finished sending.");

    bis.close();
    dos.flush();
}
```

Notice that I have added a break; command into the while loop of Server and the program work perfectly. But when I exclude it, I get this exception:

```
Test byteCount = 394
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at xml.xmlServer.saveFile2(xmlServer.java:72)
        at xml.xmlServer.run(xmlServer.java:31)
```

This only occur when I include BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream in my code. Can somebody help me explain what causes this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the filename but you aren't sending the filename. You're missing a `writeUTF()` call in the sender.

You also need to close the socket in the sender, or the `DataOutputStream`.

```
bos.write(buffer, 0, bytesCount);
```

Really this should be

```
dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesCount);
```